# Python: nesting classes without complicating imports

Tags: python, class, object, variables

Conceptual problem: I have a file called shape containing classes for lines, squares, rectangles etc like so ...

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length

class Square(Line):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super().__init__(length)

    def area(self):
        print(self.length * self.length)
```

Currently to create a Square shape I run :

```
mySquare = shape.Square(5) # 5 being the length of the sides.
```

'shape' refers to my file shape.py, and Square refers to the class Square within the file.  If I nested Square within a class called Shape, would I then have to run :

```
$ square = shape.Shape.Square(5)
```

I want to create a Class Attribute for "shape" to list all the instances of shape.  Is nesting the shapes withing a 'shape' class the correct way to accomplish this?

This is a mental stumbling block for me and would appreciate help in understanding the best way to approach this situation.  It seems this would be a common problem as applications get more complex, especially when building API's whilst keeping naming and imports as simple as possible.

Comment: Sorry, but the question you posted is not super clear. Eg what is `shape.Shape` ? Is there a class called `Shape`? I understand that there is a file called `shape`.

Comment: not sure I understand your question 100% but probably easiest is if all of your classes inherit from a `Shape` base class the `__init__` function of this Shape class can do the book keeping of the created classes. you also had to implement the __delete__ function and you had to use weak references though if you want to detect destruction of Shapes.

you had to be sure as well, that you always call super in each implementation if `__init__`

Comment: I have edited the question in the hope of making it clearer.  I think @gelonida is pretty close to answering my question.  If I understand you correctly, I don't nest the class, just inherit, and use the Shape class and weak references to keep track of each instance created?  Also Line in this example would need to call super and inherit from class Shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this roughly what you're looking for:

```
import weakref

class Shape:
    all_shapes = []
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.all_shapes.append(weakref.ref(self))

    @classmethod
    def get_all_shapes(cls):
        for wref in cls.all_shapes:
            shape = wref()
            if shape:
                yield shape

class Line(Shape):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super().__init__(length)
        self.length = length

class Square(Line):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super().__init__(length)

    def area(self):
        print(self.length * self.length)



l = Line(1)
l2 = Line(2)
print(list(Shape.get_all_shapes()))
del l
print(list(Shape.get_all_shapes()))
s = Square(5)
print(list(Shape.get_all_shapes()))
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I need, now I just need to setup my __repr__ methods to get them printing correctly. I take it @classmethod is what keeps the 'all_shapes' list of instances updated?

Comment: Note: @classmethod's are executed on the class rather than the instance. Explained here : https://youtu.be/sPiWg5jSoZI  7:07